# No module named virtualenvwrapper; virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have used virtualenvwrapper for some months now, and today I installed python2.6 from source to use tox.

All of a sudden I get:

```
$ cdwebapi 
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
```

Wrapper is installed:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
The directory '/home/cchilders/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/cchilders/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr>=1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in /home/cchilders/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
```

If I try to source again:

$ src

```
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
--no-deps: command not found
```

This is what I sourced:

```
# VIRTUALENVWRAPPER
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/work_projects
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

My venv still exists:

```
$ which python
/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/mysite/bin/python

(mysite) cchilders:~/work_projects/core/unver/mysite (master) 
$ which pip
/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/mysite/bin/pip
```

Changing bashrc to:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/work_projects
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

causes:

```
$ cdwebapi 
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
```

I just removed and reinstalled virtualenvwrapper and same issue. How can I calm these messages and fix the wrapper? Thank you